# Show record only consists unique reference key with different values on the other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm so sorry, i forgot the other situation, so i need to repost back this issue even though i already tried using NOT IN and NOT EXISTS BUT it didn't worked.

I have table A as below:-

```
id | room_id| room_status
 1 |   16    |  Out
 2 |   2     |  Out
 3 |   4     |  Out
 4 |   16    |   In
 5 |   3     |   In
 6 |   10    |   In
```

"Out" means the room is free to book. "In" means the room is occupied and cannot be selected.

Also have table B as follow:-

```
room_id  | Own_by
   2     | Comp A
   3     | Comp A
   4     | Comp A
  10     | Comp A
  16     | Comp A
  20     | Comp A
```

Desired output:-

```
room_id
   2
   4
   3
  20
```

Old issue: i would like to show room_id 3 also because it's currently been selected but also can change to other room which is room_id 2, 4 with room_status "Out". I don't want room_id 16, 10 to show up because they're not currently selected and already occupied. - this one already working, thanks to @P.Salmon and @GordonLinoff.

New issue : Also need to show room_id 20 which is not in table A. How can I do this? Really appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm lost too , what does currently selected mean?

Comment: room id 3 is currently selected but can also change other room which is room id 2 and 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand currently selected but perhaps this

```
select id,room_id,room_status
from t
where id = (select max(id) from t t1 where t1.room_id = t.room_id)
and (room_status = 'out' or room_id = 3)
```

Where max(id) is assumed to be home to latest status. and the status for room 3 is irrelevant.

```
+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | room_id | room_status |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    2 |       2 | Out         |
|    3 |       4 | Out         |
|    5 |       3 | In          |
+------+---------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @P.Salmon. im so bad at this, never thought the query is simple as that

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want all the `out` rooms and the one that is selected.  That sounds like `or`:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.status = 'out' or
      a.room_id = 3;
```

You seem to have multiple rows per room, which is odd.  So perhaps this is:

```
select a.*
from a
where room_id = 3 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from a a2
                  where a2.room_id = a.room_id and
                        a2.status = 'in'
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, your method also working on my problem

Comment: @alexis . . . It seems like the logic that you intend.